# Question on showing function in a control system block

Tags: control, transfer-function

I am trying to add a function to a control system diagram. I have a constant F being fed back into the diagram but it depends on a signal 'v'. In equations I directly used a signum function but for the diagram and to get a proper transfer function which I can use, I am having trouble showing that in the diagram. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: "Constant depends on v" is an oxymoron.

Comment: @EugeneSh. not exactly. If v is zero there is no rolling resistance or F_{roll}. and it opposes the motion so that is why I used a signum function.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something like this in the past:

[image]

Comment: Not to be rude but may I ask why does the picture seem a 1 by 1 replica of mine (except for the representation of the signum function)?

Comment: "I am having trouble showing that in the diagram. Any suggestions would be appreciated. " That above picture is a suggestion.